# MacBook Pro won't shutdown

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown

My MacBook Pro seemed to get hung up in Chrome. Was able to quit Chrome and all other apps running (Mail and TextEdit) and tried to restart. Screen went black, trackpad still moving cursor but didn't restart. Tried to force it by holding down power button but now it won't shut down either. Also tried command-option-eject with no effect. Can't get to Apple Store until tomorrow. Aside from waiting/hoping for battery to drain is there any other way I can force it to shutdown or restart.

Comment: What model Macbook Pro do you have? it’s odd that forcibly shutting the machine down (holding power button) doesn’t do the trick - how long did you press the power button for? 10+ seconds should forcibly shut the machine down regardless of the hanging process.

Comment: Sorry for the appended comment. Here’s the support article: [At least 10 seconds is necessary](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)